# How to debug react performance on localhost

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have react app running on `localhost:3000`. I have created very basic application (nothing I haven't did before), but my app performance is poor.

[image: bad performance react]

My button contains simple transition CSS attribute and as you can see above the performance results are very slow.

```
button{
    background: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 153, 0);
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 300ms all ease-in-out;
}
button:hover{
    background: rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
```

I have tried using [react performance tool chrome extension](https://github.com/nitin42/react-perf-devtool) but the result are below:

[image]

Although I followed the documentation it refuses to work.

Step one: `npm install react-perf-devtool`

Step Two (index.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
const { registerObserver } = require('react-perf-devtool');
const options = {
  shouldLog: true,
  port: 8080,
  timeout: 12000 // Load the extension after 12 sec.
}

function callback(measures) {
  console.log(measures);
}

// assign the observer to the global scope, as the GC will delete it otherwise
window.observer = registerObserver(options, callback);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Also tried:

- Deleting the app
- Reinstall it
- Remove components and check if they causing the problem
- **Run different app that works perfect**

What can cause poor performance on so basic react application?

Comment: Did you try different browsers? Did you try classic react devtools? Are you sure you don't have something stupid (eg. a loop) somewhere in your code?

Comment: @k-wasilewski I'm sure, there is nothing but design and react router in my current project. Same on Edge browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by image decoding, by using chrome dev tools I entered `performance` tab and was able to see `image decoding` value with hude loading and processing time.

So I figured out that probably because I converted Illustrator file from svg to jpg.

I solved that by uploading my file to online convertor tool and converted it to webp (could convert it to any extension and it probably would of worked).

Once I did that the performance was fast as usual.